# KC-130: What are the four tanks/tube on the wings in between the engines used for?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, feature-identification

On the KC-130, what are the 4 tanks/tube on the wings in between the engines used for?

I've seen them in photos but without explanation. I cannot find any mention of them whatsoever. If not storage tanks then what else would they be used for?

Answer (score 10):

The tanks between the engines on each wing are external fuel tanks. The pods outboard of the #1 and #4 engines are aerial refueling pods which house the hoses and drogues that are reeled out when refueling other aircraft.

[This page](https://theaviationist.com/2012/01/12/kc-130j/) has several examples of the outboard pods trailing drogues for refueling.  These pods are unique to KC- and MC-130 variants. One example:

[image]

The inboard external tanks (between engines 1 & 2 and 3 & 4) are found on most variants of the C-130.